# How to judge if two time series are similar?

Tags: time-series, similarity

this question troubles me for two days. Now i am comparing the similarity of two time series data. The approach i know so far is to calculate the distance between them. Here, i choose the Dynamic Time Warping(DTW) to compute their distance. As a result, there is a warping path together with their DTW distance. Now my question is, how can i judge whether these two are similar based on this distance? Is there any threshold defined for this problem?
My intuition tells me that, if they are identical, then the distance between them would be 0. 
Can anyone help me deal with this question?

Answer (score 1):

Using distance measure on Time Series is always risky and yes, you need to define some threshold. The value will depend on your data. (It is all hit and trial approach). 
Further,You can also refer to the paper "A review on time series data mining".

link:

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.454.773&rep=rep1&type=pdf

In the paper, you can find various approach to find the similarity in Time Series

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use some simple statistical methods like finding the correlation between the two sets of data? You could do this in Excel quite easily - see this tutorial http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/correlation.html